# When first time enter the arrangement of items is OK, but if I refresh it it will screw up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, jscrollpane

Please refer to ***
When first time enter the arrangement of items is OK(three items as a row),  but if I refresh it it will screw up
Can someone point me any direction ?
Thanks in advance !

Edit:
Is there any differences between refresh and using the link to enter ?
Edit:
**This problem only happen in Chrome browser**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure that you include all of your CSS files above the JS files in the head of your document. In webkit based browsers (e.g. Safari and Chrome) there is sometimes problems calculating dimensions if the CSS is included below the JS.