# Any differences between refresh a page and enter a page in webkit browser ?(tricky)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webkit

When I start a webkit browser instance and enter http://localhost， the result of $this.innerWidth() is right (I used jQuery).
But if I tried to refresh the page, the result of $this.innerWidth() will change, which is wrong.  It seems no sense, as I think refresh is the same to start a new page loading.

And this only happens in webkit browser, any recommendations ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you be more specific? When (on page load, straight in the header, etc.), how and on what are you using `innerWidth()`? What's the wrong value (is it bigger, smaller, 0, random)?

Comment: Refreshing is not the same as reloading. Some `inputs` values remains too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [When first time enter the arrangement of items is OK, but if I refresh it it will screw up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673313/when-first-time-enter-the-arrangement-of-items-is-ok-but-if-i-refresh-it-it-will)